# Passing a dictionary to a python programme

Tags: python

A main Python - (no code available at the moment)  programme needs to call my Python programme - Evaluate_T+M.py - that evaluates the data on two dictionaries.
The main Programme has two dictionaries Dict1 and Dict2.
The main contains

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["python", "Evaluate_T+Mmyscript.py", Dict1, Dict2, 10084628])
```

The thing is, I do not want a copy of the Dicts passed on as both dictionaries are large. How can I achieve this?

I want to pass two dictionaries to an external Python programme without duplicating the directories. So to save space since the dictionaries are large in size.

I cannot change the main code that calls my code.

Comment: how large are they exactly? You could use pickle objects for export and import and delete them afterwards.

Comment: Make the code you want to run a function, import it and call it.

Comment: It is not going to work like that anyway, because `subprocess.call` only deals with strings.